Ask exogeneity of linear regression model
2.2.1 The Gauss-Markov theorem
We assume the linear regression model (2.1) $$
Y=\beta_1 X_1+\cdots+\beta_p X_p+\varepsilon,
$$with

exogeneity: $\mathrm{E}(\varepsilon \mid X)=0$;

Previously, the author also mention that "It is often assumed that "random error" $\varepsilon$ has zero mean, uncorrelated with covariates $X$, which is referred to as exogenous variables."
Are these two statements equivalent? I am confused. For me, "random error" $\varepsilon$ has zero mean represents $E(\epsilon)=0$ and
uncorrelated with covariates $X$ represents $Cov(X, \epsilon)=0$.
